# A problem on conditional expectation and inner product in a Hilbert space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two random elements in a Hilbert space. Then I have seen in a paper to use the following
$$E[\langle X,Y \rangle] = E[\langle E[X|Y], Y\rangle].$$ 
Here $E[X|Y]$ is also an element of the Hilbert space.

Comment: State explicitly what you want to ask in the question and write some your own effort.

Comment: If your question is why this is true, this is just [the tower rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), and the fact that for any deterministic function $f$, $\mathbb{E}[f(Y)|Y] = f(Y)$. $$\mathbb{E}[ f(X,Y)] = \mathbb{E}\Big[ \mathbb{E}[f(X,Y)|Y] \Big] = \mathbb{E}\Big[ f\big(\mathbb{E}[X|Y],Y \big) \Big]$$

Comment: @stochasticboy321 How do you justify your last equality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a Hilbert space $H$, the expectation of a random element $X$ is defined to be the element $z$ such that for every $x \in H$,
$$E[\langle x, X \rangle] = \langle x, \mu\rangle.$$
and we denote $\mu$ by $E[X]$. 
Therefore, for every $y$ in $H$, 
\begin{align}
& E[\langle E(X|Y), y\rangle] \\
= & \langle E[E(X|Y)], y\rangle \\
= & \langle E(X), y \rangle. \tag{$*$}
\end{align}

Now replace $y$ in $(*)$ by $Y$ to get
$$E[\langle E(X|Y), Y\rangle] = \langle E(X), Y\rangle \tag{$**$}$$

Now take expectations on both sides of $(**)$ and notice that the left side of $(**)$ is already a nonrandom constant, therefore,
$$E[\langle E(X|Y), Y\rangle] = E[\langle E(X), Y\rangle] = \langle E(X), E(Y)\rangle.$$

In the last equality we used the definition for $E(Y)$.

To show that $E[\langle X, Y \rangle] = \langle E(X), E(Y) \rangle$. Again start with for any $y \in H$, we have
$$E[\langle X, y\rangle] = \langle E(X), y\rangle.$$
Similar replacement, then taking expectations on both sides give that
$$E[\langle X, Y \rangle] = E[\langle E(X), Y\rangle] = \langle E(X), E(Y) \rangle.$$

Comment: Can you please give any reference of the definition you wrote in the first line. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. One reference is _The Coordinate-Free Approach to Linear Models_ by *Michael J. Wichura*. What I wrote is given as a definition in section $2$ of Chapter $3$. Another more technical reference has related material is *Morris L.Eaton*'s *Multivariate Statistics: A Vector Space Approach*. See Example $2.1$ therein.

Comment: Thanks. Nice application of Riesz representation theorem which I just learnt in a course.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. Yes it is.

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E\big(\langle X , Y\rangle\big)
& = \mathsf E\Big(\mathsf E\big(\langle X , Y\rangle\mid \color{blue}{Y}\big)\Big)
\\[1ex] 
& = \mathsf E\Big(\big\langle \mathsf E(X\mid \color{blue}{Y}) , Y\big\rangle\Big)
\end{align}$$

So what's the problem?